# SOAP message error with addiotional XML tags

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, soap, saxparser

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://172.29.165.219:8090/abc/services/Abc";
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<getUserInfo>\n"
                         "<email>%@</email>\n"
                         "<pwd>%@</pwd>\n"
                         "</getUserInfo>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n", @"babla.sharan@tcs.com",@"UGFzc0AxMjM="//,@"50006F0063006B0065007400500043000000-444556494345454D00",@"PocketPC"
                         ];
NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [RequestGenerator -generateSOAPRequestWithURLString:urlString soapMessage:soapMessage contentType:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" action:@"getUserInfo"];
WebServiceHandler *connection = [[WebServiceHandler alloc]init];
```

For the Above code, it works fine, but when I add additional Tag  as parent tag to id and password

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://172.29.165.219:8090/abc/services/Abc";
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<getUserInfo>\n"
                         **"<ABC>\n"**
                                                     "<email>%@</email>\n"
                         "<pwd>%@</pwd>\n"
                                                     **"</ABC>\n"**
                         "</getUserInfo>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n", @"babla.sharan@tcs.com",@"UGFzc0AxMjM="//,@"50006F0063006B0065007400500043000000-444556494345454D00",@"PocketPC"
                         ];
NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [RequestGenerator generateSOAPRequestWithURLString:urlString soapMessage:soapMessage contentType:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" action:@"getUserInfo"];
WebServiceHandler *connection = [[WebServiceHandler alloc]init];
```

It shows exception and get this error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.

It doesn't even allow me to hit the server.

Comment: have you tried making the tag ABC like <ABC></ABC> instead of </ABC>?

Comment: at server side, do you have this new tag recognition?

Answer (score 0):

Here in second soap message you are sending an additional parent tag for you information, which may not be recognized by you server. If this tag is optional than there should be no problem at all, but if it is undesired then you should not use it. Below are the excerpts from W3.org(http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/) .... which tells about the receiving and processing of soap request.

```
A SOAP application receiving a SOAP message MUST process that message by performing 
    the following actions in the order listed below:

         1. Identify all parts of the SOAP message intended for that application 
         2. Verify that all mandatory parts identified in step 1 are supported by
 the  application for this message (see section 4.2.3) and process them accordingly.
 If this is   not the case then discard the message .
 The processor MAY ignore optional parts identified in step 1 without affecting the outcome of the processing.
        3. If the SOAP application is not the ultimate destination of the message then
     remove all parts identified in step 1 before forwarding the message.


  Processing a message or a part of a message requires that the SOAP processor 
  understands, among other things, the exchange pattern being used (one way, 
  request/response, multicast, etc.), the role of the recipient in that pattern, the 
  employment (if any) of RPC mechanisms such as the one documented in section 7, the 
  representation or encoding of data, as well as other semantics necessary for correct 
  processing
```